# Should I reverse order a queryset before slicing the first N records, or count it to slice the last N records?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

Let's say I want to get the last 50 records of a query that returns around 10k records, in a table with 1M records. I could do (at the computational cost of ordering):

```
data = MyModel.objects.filter(criteria=something).order_by('-pk')[:50]
```

I could also do (at the cost of 2 database hits):

```
# assume I don't care about new records being added between
# the two queries being executed
index = MyModel.objects.filter(criteria=something).count()
data = MyModel.objects.filter(criteria=something)[index-50:]
```

Which is better for just an ordinary relational database with no indexing on the `criteria` (eg postgres in my case; no columnar storage or anything fancy)? Most importantly, ***why?***

Does the answer change if the table or queryset is significantly bigger (eg 100k records from a 10M row table)?

Comment: Does Django impose a meaningful order when you use `.filter`? Usually, in a SQL database, *last 50 rows* is only meaningful if you use `order by` or its equivalent. Running the same query again might not return rows in the same order.

Comment: I'm asking this in the context of creating a dashboard where I just want to display some reasonably recent customer reviews. The ordering strictness isn't important for this particular case.

Comment: *Reasonably recent* is also meaningless in the absence of `order by` or its equivalent.

Comment: You're right, I'm relying on the queryset being returned ordered by an autoincrement pk, and it may not be. Again, it's good enough for this application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one is going to be very slow

```
 data = MyModel.objects.filter(criteria=something)[index-50:]
```

Why because it translates into

```
 SELECT * FROM myapp_mymodel OFFEST (index-50)
```

You are not enforcing any ordering here, so the server is going to have to calulcate the result set and jump to the end of it and that's going to involve a lot of reading and will be very slow. Let us not forgot that count() queries aren't all that hot either.

OTH, this one is going to be fast

```
data = MyModel.objects.filter(criteria=something).order_by('-pk')[:50]
```

You are reverse ordering on the primary key and getting the first 50. And the first 50 you can fetch equally quickly with

```
data = MyModel.objects.filter(criteria=something).order_by('pk')[:50]
```

So this is what you really should be doing

```
data1 = MyModel.objects.filter(criteria=something).order_by('-pk')[:50]
data2 = MyModel.objects.filter(criteria=something).order_by('pk')[:50]
```

The cost of ordering on the primary key is very low.